# How the bool operator of std::shared_ptr is trrigered in the expression(i.e. `bool is_empty = shared_ptr1 && shared_ptr2;` )?

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Gaven that `cur_front_res` and `cur_back_res` are both shared_ptr, how the bool operator of std::shared_ptr is trigered in the expression(i.e. `bool is_empty = cur_front_res && cur_back_res;` )?

Just because `&&` always cause built-in conversion if the operands(i.e. before `&&` and after `&&`) is not an bool type?

[The code snippet below works indeed](https://godbolt.org/z/hhE3j4546).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> cur_front_res; // Empty shared_ptr
    std::shared_ptr<int> cur_back_res(new int(42)); // Shared_ptr pointing to an int

    bool is_empty = cur_front_res && cur_back_res;

    if (is_empty) {
        std::cout << "Both cur_front_res and cur_back_res are not empty" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Either cur_front_res or cur_back_res is empty" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just because `&&` always cause built-in conversion if the operands(i.e. before `&&` and after `&&`) is not an `bool` type?

Basically yes.

But the `bool` conversion is somewhat special: even though `operator bool`s are usually `explicit` (including the one for `shared_ptr`), there are a few cases where it can be called implicitly (["contextual bool conversion"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions)). Among other things, those include operands of boolean operators, `if`/`while`/`for` conditions, etc.